# "Перекомплектация" или "корректировка" кода товара?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика

Как правильно: "перекомплектация" или "корректировка" кода товара на складе?

Comment: Может, лучше "перекодирование товара"?

Comment: "Перекомплектация" может ввести в заблуждение. Обычно однокоренные с "комплектацией" слова используют, чтобы сказать, хватает ли чего либо. Например, "личный состав укомплектован". А "перекомплектация" может навести на мысль, что часть товара заменяется другим, когда как ничего такого не происходит. А вообще, не помешало бы пояснение, о чём речь.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о манипуляции именно с кодом товара (номером, артикулом, штрихкодом и т. п.), то представляется более уместным вариант с "корректировкой", см. [Карту слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Корректировка (кода товара)  в значении "внесение поправок (в код товара)" точно указывает, что происходит с кодом товара, а именно — некое его (кода) изменение, правка, уточнение. При этом "корректировка кода" необязательно означает, что с самим товаром что-то произошло (изменилось количество, произошла замена части комплекта и пр.) — скорее, просто изменилось обозначение товара в документах.

Если же речь о некоем перемещении товара / изменении его конфигурации, то лучше подходит "перекомплектация (товара)", см. [Карту слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F). Так мы указываем, что физически произошло что-то с самим товаром: изменилась упаковка, состав, количество товара, то есть комплект того, что в него входит. И в таком случае код товара тоже может быть изменён, но акцент падает именно на физические свойства товара.

**ВЫВОД**

Если мы хотим подчеркнуть, что изменился код товара и это нашло отражение в документации/маркировке, то лучше подходит "корректировка кода товара".

Если мы хотим подчеркнуть, что изменились физические свойства товара (состав, упаковка, количество, комплектация и т. д.), то лучше подходит "перекомплектация товара".

Важно учесть, что при перекомплектации товара в любом случае что-то да корректируется (его код, номенклатура, отметка в документах и др.), так что речь тут о контексте и акценте: на что именно мы хотим обратить внимание собеседника.